# How to make simple login screen with forget password in ADF?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a users table that contain user and password 
I will use it in the login logic 
And i will add a button to reset password ( will enter his email) 
I came from java background and i can make easily with ejb 
But using pure adf how will i 
1 - validate of the user and password is correct 
2- when user reset password   , i will add a recoed in other table with the user id and a temp code , how to achive that ?

Could someine tell the basic Idea , and if there an example could you guide me to its ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a table Update_user_password with required fields which is child table and parent table should be one like user_management . After clicking Forget password, popup should be called with "createInsert" method. Enter the username and use value change listerner to call the method, whether username is available,if available password and save button should be made visible state or else it should be in hidden state. Don't forget to set autosubmit='true' for input text field. Once the username is available in parent table and then enter the password and save it. That's it from adf side and make a trigger for this child table like once the data is saved, trigger should happen as you have to get the password from child table and update the password in parent table using username as input from child to parent. For more security one you have mail the password to user and update the same password in parent table and after that you can update the password as you can.

Comment: thanks Vignesh for your reply
if i've get you right :
I already have a user table with UserName, password 
when he click forget password , a popup will open
then he will enter his email 
i will email him a temp password , then , he will enter his user name , temp password , and the new password ,
if successed , then update the temp password in child table , and parent table with the trigger

Comment: Yes, I have not yet worked in this type. But I guess that it will work successfully. Update the temp password in child and later on in parent .